# Having problems with an extra qualification error in c++11 compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I'm a c++11 student and I'm having trouble with an extra qualification error.

I have a class declared in a .h file and the implementation for a boolean function in a separate .cpp file.

The class definition is as follows:

```
class Order{
      std::string customer, product;
      std::vector<std::string> itemList;

      bool validName(std::string name);
      bool isCustomerName(std::string name);
      bool isProductName(std::string name);
      bool isItemName(std::string name);

public:

      Order(std::vector<std::string> line);
      void print(){
      void graph(std::ofstream os);
};//class Order
```

all of the functions are implemented in a separate cpp file, and I have scoped all of the functions in the following manner:

```
Order::Order(std::vector<std::string> line){
```

or

```
bool Order::isCustomerName(std::string name){
```

When I try to compile the cpp file, this error comes up:

```
error: extra qualification ‘Order::’ on member ‘Order’ [-fpermissive]
```

After looking it up, it seems to be an error related to using the scope operator either in the class definition on the same function or some kind of double use of the scope operator.

I haven't encapsulated the implementations in the cpp file in a separate namespace and I have only included the corresponding .h file for the cpp file. Can someone please give me a little push in the direction I need to look at to solve this issue?

Thanks

---

This is the top of the cpp file:

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <string> 
#include "order.h"
```

this is a sample function from the same cpp:

```
bool Order::isProductName(std::string name){ 
    if (name.size() > 0 && isalpha(name[0])) 
        return true; 
    return false; }
```

The class definition listed above is literally everything that's in the .h for class Order.

the top of the .h is:

```
#pragma once 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <string> 
#include "util.h"
```

Comment: Can you please provide more of your cpp file?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't define your members inside the class definition?

Comment: This is the top of the cpp file:

Comment: #include <fstream>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  #include "order.h"

this is a sample function from the same cpp:

bool Order::isProductName(std::string name){
                  if (name.size() > 0 && isalpha(name[0]))
                          return true;
                  return false;
          }

The class definition listed above is literally everything that's in the .h for class Order. the top of the .h is:
 #pragma once
   #include <fstream>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <string>
  #include "util.h"

Comment: wow sorry will try that again

Comment: cpp is:

#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <string> 
#include "order.h"

Comment: this is a sample function from the same cpp://///////////

bool Order::isProductName(std::string name){ if (name.size() > 0 && isalpha(name[0])) return true; return false; }

Comment: The class definition listed above is literally everything that's in the .h for class Order.

Comment: the top of the .h is: /////////////#pragma once #include <fstream> #include <iostream> #include <vector> #include <string> #include "util.h"

Comment: @jKim83: Put those things in your question, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line in your class:

```
 void print(){
```

I believe you meant

```
 void print();
```

Because of the way C++ compiles, when you say `#include "order.h"` the compiler is literally copy and pasting the contents of order.h into your cpp file. So it sees that you have opened this function definition for print, and declared some local functions inside of your member function print (a gcc extension), and then you eventually close the function out at the line labeled `};//class Order`. This looks to you like the end of the class definition, but it's actually the end of your function. The function definitions later on that are in your cpp file are seen as being inside the class body, which confuses the compiler.

Comment: gah... thanks. Working on a vi editor and managed to miss that syntax error.